# How to Reference a List C#

Tags: c#, linked-list, ref, writetofile

I'm trying to create a procedure that writes a list to file but I'm not sure how to reference the list so the procedure can access it and write to the file

WriteToFile Procedure: The issue with it being DinoList doesnt exist in the current context so I need to reference it which I'm not to sure how to do.

```
        static void WriteToFile()
        { 
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("E:/Work/Dinosaur.txt");
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream);
            foreach (Dinosaur d in DinoList)
            {
                writer.Write(d.Name);
                writer.Write(d.Classification);
                writer.Write(d.Sex);
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Procedure that the list is currently in, if I move it to main I assume I'll need to reference it in to this procedure as well so this procedure still works.

```
        static void PrintAllDino()
        {
            LinkedList<Dinosaur> DinoList = new LinkedList<Dinosaur>();

            Dinosaur Dino1 = new Dinosaur();
            Dino1.Name = "Tyrannosaurus Rex";
            Dino1.Classification = "Carnivorous";
            Dino1.Sex = 'M';

            Dinosaur Dino2 = new Dinosaur();
            Dino2.Name = "Velociraptor";
            Dino2.Classification = "Carnivorous";
            Dino2.Sex = 'F';

            Dinosaur Dino3 = new Dinosaur();
            Dino3.Name = "Procompsognathus";
            Dino3.Classification = "Carnivorous";
            Dino3.Sex = 'M';

            void printList()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The current dinosaurs stored in the list are: ");
                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                foreach (Dinosaur d in DinoList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + d.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Classification: " + d.Classification);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sex " + d.Sex);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }
            }
            DinoList.AddLast(Dino1);
            DinoList.AddLast(Dino2);
            DinoList.AddLast(Dino3);
            printList();
            Console.WriteLine(DinoList.Count);

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Dinosaur Name: ");
```

```
        static void MainMenuSelection(int selection)
        {
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected to create a new dinosaur.");
                    DinoInserstionMenu();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected to remove a dinosaur from the list.");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected to display a specific dinosaurs information.");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected to print out all the dinosaur details stored in the list.");
                    PrintAllDino();
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected to load from a file.");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("You have selected to save to a file.");
                    WriteToFile(DinoList);
                    DisplayMainMenu();
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    break;
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Im trying to write the dino list to a file, I have the procedure called WriteToFile with the code to write to a file but the name ` DinoList ` doesn't exist in the current context so I need to reference it which I'm not sure how to do. @sTrenat

Comment: just declare your method as `static void WriteToFile(LinkedList<Dinosaur> dinoList)` and pass it as argument

Comment: Not sure what you mean by pass as argument ?

Comment: i mean call it like `WriteToFile(DinoList)` when you want to save your dino list to file

Comment: Do not use a BinaryWriter to write text! In fact try to avoid it whenever you can

Comment: Yeah still not sure what you mean man.

Comment: I've only ever used BinaryWriter what else do you suggest @TaW ?

Comment: [Either StreamWriter or File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-write-text-to-a-file) - You will also need to decide on separators.

Comment: Using that how would I do what I'm trying to do then ?

Comment: Do study the MSDN example! - The way you enumerate the List seems fine with me.

Comment: That way, you need to modify your `PrintAllDino` method to make it like `PrintAllDino(LinkedList<Dinosaur> dinoList)`, then in your MainMenuSelection create your list. Now you can pass it to both PrintAllDino and WriteToFile

Comment: Just tried that didnt work still getting this error by doing that "The name ` DinoList ` doesn't exist within the current context"  @sTrenat

Comment: You'r misusing static methods, these are made for some utils class that doesn't manage your objects

For your use case, you should create class like `DinoManager` with private field `DinoList`, add public method `MainMenuSelection`, and in your `PrintAllDino/WriteToFile` methods use this private field `DinoList`. At the and, in you'r main method create `new DinoManager()` and call it's `MainMenuSelection` method

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate your DinoList as a static variable and access it within your Program.. Initialize it "outside" of any function to make it, global.

```
// This will make it accessible by any method under this class.
public static LinkedList<Dinosaur> DinoList = new LinkedList<Dinosaur>();
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Call your Print and Write methods.
    return;
}

static void PrintAllDino()
{
    // Dont create the DinoList object here, just update DinoList here and Print it.
}
```

If you dont want to create a global variable, you can pass the DinoList as an argument.

```
static void WriteToFile(LinkedList<Dinosaur> DinoList) 
{
    //do what you need with DinoList
}

// And whereever you are calling WriteToFile, you can pass the DinoList
WriteToFile(DinoList);
```

---

Following is a working example

```
public class Program
{
    // This will make it accessible by any method under this class.
    public static LinkedList<Dinosaur> DinoList = new LinkedList<Dinosaur>();
    public class Dinosaur
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Classification { get; set; }
        public char Sex { get; set; }
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int selection = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (selection == 4)
                break;

            MainMenuSelection(selection);
                
        }
        return;
    }
    public static void MainMenuSelection(int selection)
    {
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1: // Create Dinos
                CreateDinos();
                break;
            case 2:
                PrintAllDinos();
                break;
            case 3:
                WriteToFile();
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
                break;
        }
    }
    public static void CreateDinos()
    {
        Dinosaur Dino1 = new Dinosaur();
        Dino1.Name = "Tyrannosaurus Rex";
        Dino1.Classification = "Carnivorous";
        Dino1.Sex = 'M';

        Dinosaur Dino2 = new Dinosaur();
        Dino2.Name = "Velociraptor";
        Dino2.Classification = "Carnivorous";
        Dino2.Sex = 'F';

        Dinosaur Dino3 = new Dinosaur();
        Dino3.Name = "Procompsognathus";
        Dino3.Classification = "Carnivorous";
        Dino3.Sex = 'M';

        DinoList.AddLast(Dino1);
        DinoList.AddLast(Dino2);
        DinoList.AddLast(Dino3);

    }
    public static void PrintAllDinos()
    {
        foreach (Dinosaur d in DinoList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + d.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Classification: " + d.Classification);
            Console.WriteLine("Sex " + d.Sex);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
    static void WriteToFile()
    {
        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\\Temp\\dinoList.txt");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
        foreach (Dinosaur d in DinoList)
        {
            writer.Write($"{d.Name},");
            writer.Write($"{d.Classification},");
            writer.Write(d.Sex.ToString());
            writer.WriteLine();
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing as argument works fine other than the procedure to call it with the error being "The name ` DinoList ` doesn't exist within the current context" im trying to call it in a switch statement could that be the issue ?

Comment: If I could send you all my code I think it would make it easier for you to understand the error? @Jawad

Comment: can you update your post and show where you are calling WriteToFile method?

Comment: I added your post to show where the method is called to, calling the method outside of this works but in my case I need it to be called within this location @Jawad

Comment: No problem @Jawad

Comment: @JackBarnes see my example above. Hopefully it will help. I didnt write any of the Comments for brevity.